# Error from starting a view from an activity

Tags: android, view

```
public class MAINActivity extends TabActivity {    
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Settings")
            .setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_user))
       .setContent(new Intent(this, TwoDScrollView.class)));
........
}

 public class TwoDScrollView extends Activity {

 private RelativeLayout container;
 private int currentX;
 private int currentY;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.design);

container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

int top = 0;
int left = 0;

ImageView image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
container.addView(image1, layoutParams);

ImageView image2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
left+= 100;
layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
container.addView(image2, layoutParams);

ImageView image3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
left= 0;
top+= 100;

layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
container.addView(image3, layoutParams);

ImageView image4 =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
left+= 100;     

layoutParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);               
container.addView(image4, layoutParams);
}     

  @Override 
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
        currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
        int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
        container.scrollBy(currentX - x2 , currentY - y2);
        currentX = x2;
        currentY = y2;
        break;
    }   
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        break;
    }
}
  return true; 
}
```

}

When I trying to add the TwoDScrollView Class to the tabbars I got an error of IllegalStateException. The specified child already has a parent. You must removeView() on the child's parent first. What does all those means?

Comment: Are you using removeView() anywhere?! "You must removeView() on the child's parent first." means that you are trying to remove views from child who has got parent.So you will have to do removeView() on the main parent View which has got this child View.Also can you please post the logcat messages as well as point to the line where exception is occuring(if you already know)?!

Comment: I never use any function called removeView, its first time I seen this term.

Comment: please post logcat messages so we can find out whats going on?!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you are implicitly inflating your layout by calling setContentView which creates a bunch of views including four ImageViews apparently in a RelativeLayout. Then you're doing findViewById  to find these ImageViews and the RelativeLayout, and after changing their margins programmatically, you add them back to the same layout which already contained them. This is why you get an exception. Those ImageViews already have a parent (the RelativeLayout) and you're trying to give them a new parent (even if it is that same RelativeLayout) without first removing them from their parent. You don't need to call `addView` at all in this case.